# how tensorflow do CNN Calculation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When study CNN, I find the blog like blow

- http://blog.csdn.net/tostq/article/details/51786265
- https://github.com/tostq/DeepLearningC/tree/master/CNN

He use C Language do cnn,that's reference Matlab DeepLearnToolbox cnn.
The code like blow

```
//---forward Propagation,InputData is image data
void cnnff(CNN* cnn,float** inputData)
{
    int outSizeW=cnn->S2->inputWidth;
    int outSizeH=cnn->S2->inputHeight;
    int i,j,r,c;

    //---the first,convolution C1
    nSize mapSize={cnn->C1->mapSize,cnn->C1->mapSize};
    nSize inSize={cnn->C1->inputWidth,cnn->C1->inputHeight};
    nSize outSize={cnn->S2->inputWidth,cnn->S2->inputHeight};
    for(i=0;i<(cnn->C1->outChannels);i++){
        for(j=0;j<(cnn->C1->inChannels);j++){
            float** mapout=cov(cnn->C1->mapData[j][i],mapSize,inputData,inSize,valid);
            addmat(cnn->C1->v[i],cnn->C1->v[i],outSize,mapout,outSize);
            for(r=0;r<outSize.r;r++)
                free(mapout[r]);
            free(mapout);
        }
        for(r=0;r<outSize.r;r++)
            for(c=0;c<outSize.c;c++)
                cnn->C1->y[i][r][c]=activation_Sigma(cnn->C1->v[i][r][c],cnn->C1->basicData[i]);
    }

    //the second，pooling S2
    outSize.c=cnn->C3->inputWidth;
    outSize.r=cnn->C3->inputHeight;
    inSize.c=cnn->S2->inputWidth;
    inSize.r=cnn->S2->inputHeight;
    for(i=0;i<(cnn->S2->outChannels);i++){
        if(cnn->S2->poolType==AvePool)
            avgPooling(cnn->S2->y[i],outSize,cnn->C1->y[i],inSize,cnn->S2->mapSize);
    }
}
```

This code I can see the value how to change and how many feature map,after the input image convolution and pooling.
So,can I see like this on the Tensorflow?

I track the Tensorflow code at tensorflow\python\client\session.py , the code like blow

```
def _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options,
            run_metadata):
  # Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the runtime.
  self._extend_graph()
  with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
    if self._created_with_new_api:
      return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(
          session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
          run_metadata, status)
    else:
      return tf_session.TF_Run(session, options,
                               feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
                               status, run_metadata)
```

When do the function "tf_session.TF_Run",it only return (loss,Accuracy
),but can't see the value how to change.

Then I track the Tensorflow code at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py ,the code like blow

```
def TF_Run(session, run_options, feed_dict, output_names, target_nodes, out_status, run_outputs):
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TF_Run(session, run_options, feed_dict, output_names, target_nodes, out_status, run_outputs)
TF_Run = _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TF_Run
```

The pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py have use _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd, I think the value how to change is on this .pyd. So,where is this .pyd source code? because this .pyd only can download by "pip install tensorflow".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean you want to know how `tf.nn.conv2d` and sorts are implemented. If you're new to TensorFlow, you'll notice that there are `layers` (e.g. `tf.layers.conv2d`) and `nn` (e.g. `tf.nn.conv2d`). `layers` are all wrappers for `nn`, so if you just want to get to the implementation right away, ignore the `layers`.

Now if you read the [documentation for `tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), it says:

> Defined in generated file: `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py`.

Just for comparison, take a look at the [documentation for `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose), which says:

> Defined in [`tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py`](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py).

Now if you click `tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py`, it actually takes you to the file where `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` is defined. But for `tf.nn.conv2d`, which you are interested in, this link does not exist. This is because you can write the layer in C++ and let TensorFlow generate the Python part, hence the text defined in **generated file**. The actual implementations are spread across three files here:

- [tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d.h)
- [tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc)
- [tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_gpu.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_gpu.h)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for how CNN works internally. Below code illustrate how conv operation is performed internally. Below code is equivalent to this tensor-flow API.

More information about this specific operation you can find it in [How to map input image with neurons in first conv layer in CNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60690923/how-to-map-input-image-with-neurons-in-first-conv-layer-in-cnn)

Note: This is just conv operation in first layer of CNN.

```
Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X,W1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')

def conv_forward(A_prev, W, b, hparameters):
"""
Implements the forward propagation for a convolution function

Arguments:
A_prev -- output activations of the previous layer, numpy array of shape (m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev)
W -- Weights, numpy array of shape (f, f, n_C_prev, n_C)
b -- Biases, numpy array of shape (1, 1, 1, n_C)
hparameters -- python dictionary containing "stride" and "pad"

Returns:
Z -- conv output, numpy array of shape (m, n_H, n_W, n_C)
cache -- cache of values needed for the conv_backward() function
"""

# Retrieve dimensions from A_prev's shape (≈1 line)  
(m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev) = A_prev.shape

# Retrieve dimensions from W's shape (≈1 line)
(f, f, n_C_prev, n_C) = W.shape

# Retrieve information from "hparameters" (≈2 lines)
stride = hparameters['stride']
pad = hparameters['pad']

# Compute the dimensions of the CONV output volume using the formula given above. Hint: use int() to floor. (≈2 lines)
n_H = int(np.floor((n_H_prev-f+2*pad)/stride)) + 1
n_W = int(np.floor((n_W_prev-f+2*pad)/stride)) + 1

# Initialize the output volume Z with zeros. (≈1 line)
Z = np.zeros((m,n_H,n_W,n_C))

# Create A_prev_pad by padding A_prev
A_prev_pad = zero_pad(A_prev,pad)

for i in range(m):                               # loop over the batch of training examples
    a_prev_pad = A_prev_pad[i]                               # Select ith training example's padded activation
    for h in range(n_H):                           # loop over vertical axis of the output volume
        for w in range(n_W):                       # loop over horizontal axis of the output volume
            for c in range(n_C):                   # loop over channels (= #filters) of the output volume

                # Find the corners of the current "slice" (≈4 lines)
                vert_start = h*stride
                vert_end = vert_start+f
                horiz_start = w*stride
                horiz_end = horiz_start+f

                # Use the corners to define the (3D) slice of a_prev_pad (See Hint above the cell). (≈1 line)
                a_slice_prev = a_prev_pad[vert_start:vert_end,horiz_start:horiz_end,:]

                # Convolve the (3D) slice with the correct filter W and bias b, to get back one output neuron. (≈1 line)
                Z[i, h, w, c] = conv_single_step(a_slice_prev,W[:,:,:,c],b[:,:,:,c])                                      

return Z


    A_prev = np.random.randn(1,64,64,3)
    W = np.random.randn(4,4,3,8)
    #Don't worry about bias , tensorflow will take care of this.
    b = np.random.randn(1,1,1,8)
    hparameters = {"pad" : 1,
                   "stride": 1}

    Z = conv_forward(A_prev, W, b, hparameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

pyd files are alike windows dynamic libraries.

This can help:
https://stackabuse.com/differences-between-pyc-pyd-and-pyo-python-files/

Maybe you need to understand how is tensorflow compiled from scratch in order to understand all your troubles with that .pyd ;)